# Is it possible to move a textview slightly out of its cardView?

Tags: android-layout, textview, android-cardview

Okay this may seem to be a easy question but trust me i have been spending hours to accomplished this. Just want to know whether it is possible to bring out a textview slightly of the right side of the cardView. Btw the texview is under many layouts such as linear layout and relative layouts.

I have tried adding this code in the xml of its parents layout as well. **android:clipToPadding="false"** and **android:clipChildren="false"** and it still doesnt work. Im not sure why it doesnt work for me. I have attached the image of how i want the layout of the textview to look like.Should i add some code in the adapter of my recyclerview? Please help. Thanks in advance

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:card_View="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_View:cardUseCompatPadding="false">



     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/random"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">




<TextView
        android:id="@+id/random2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/random3"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">



  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/random4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



  <View
        android:id="@+id/random5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>



<TextView
        android:id="@+id/this_is_the_textview_i_want_it_to_come_out_slightly"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>




        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**The code attached below is inside a cardView and the cardView will be placed in a recyclverview**

Comment: Please help guys

Comment: Can you post the XML.

Comment: @SandipSingh i have attached the xml for your reference. Hopefully u can provide me with a solution. thanks

Comment: not to forget mentioning. this cardview is being placed in a recyclerview. Does the recyclerview makes any difference here?

Comment: Please add you code in the question, it's really tough to check one XML in 4 images.

Comment: @SandipSingh ok sure

Comment: @SandipSingh i have added the xml code. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout` and `elevation` to fulfill your target.

You need to play with the elevation of the `TextView` to bring it above the `CardView`.

Try to do it in this way.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_View="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_View:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        card_View:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/random"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/random2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="kjabsfd"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/random3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/random4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:text="khfsda"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/random5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/this_is_the_textview_i_want_it_to_come_out_slightly"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="100% OFF"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/card"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome my friend. Please accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: thanks  bro its working. Thanks for your time assisting me